# How to run a script to a pod in CI/CD?

Tags: kubernetes, circleci, prisma

I deployed a PostgreSQL to Kubernetes, and also a micro-service in NodeJS. I'm using CircleCI as CI/CD.

I'm using Prisma ORM, and everytime I build a new image of my NodeJS container, I need to run a script against my PostgreSQL database. The database is running in a different pod from my NodeJS app, and it's only reachable inside the Kubernetes environment (it's not exposed to the web).

Initially I thought on creating a step in my CI/CD pipeline to run the script, however, Circleci won't be able to connect to my PostgreSQL pod, since it's not reachable from outside.

Also, I don't want to run the script everytime a new pod is deployed, only when I build a new Docker image.

The command I need to run is `prisma migrate deploy`, which will check my DB migrations in my NodeJS schema.

How should I do it?

Comment: Just to clarify: When docker image is build (outside of k8s cluster), you want some script to run and perform some stuff on db (inside k8s cluster). Correct?

Comment: @golobitch yes, that's correct. CircleCi builds the docker image, pushes to docker hub, then runs a script to deploy to kubernetes. I also need to run a script against my DB, which is in another pod.

Comment: apparently you will need to give access to CircleCI of your pod. So you can give circleci this access and after that you can do this ```kubectl exec -it <podName> -- /bin/bash -c "ls"```. Assuming that your script that you need to run is in database pod

Comment: The problem is that the script needs the schema that it's in my micro-service repository

Comment: From where did this micro-service repository now came into the play? And where is this? I do not see any mention of micro-service repository in your question

Comment: This micro-service is mine, it's a NodeJS application (it's written in the first sentence). It connectes to my PostgreSQL pod and it has it's own database in PostgreSQL. Everytime a new build is made, I need to run `prisma migrate deploy` to check for DB migrations. This repository fires the CircleCI to build and deploy in Kubernetes

Comment: For migrations? I don't think this is correct approach. If you need to run database migrations I think that preferred way is with init containers: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to summon up my comments in answer.

You want to run database migrations when docker image is build. Best way, to run migrations in kubernetes cluster is with the help of init containers.

### What is init container?

Init containers are containers that starts in the same pod as "main" container, but it starts before any other container. In init containers, you should have some initialization logic. You can look at init containers just like class constructors. They are in charge of doing initialization.

[image]

As you can see in above image, init container is performing some action (seed) on uninitialized DB, and main application is working with initialized DB.

Like in constructors, there is also some "drawbacks" with init containers. What happens if constructor throws an exception? You will not be able to use the object, because it hasn't been initialized. Same thing with init containers. If init container does not exit with success code, main container will not start. If init container fails, then it will do whatever you defined in restartPolicy.

But what happens when you set restartPolicy to always and init container fails? Well,...it will try again. And then again...so you need to be sure that your code is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

### Can I have multiple init containers?

Sure, why not? But they will be executed in sequence. And also, if one init container fails, all other, after the failed one, will not be executed.

I have also did a little recap from [Kubernetes Patterns: The Init Containers](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-patterns-the-init-container-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm @c6o/kubeclient` for this and use the exec command to execute commands in a running pod if you want to do it in NodeJS code.

```
const cluster = new Cluster(options) // can be {} if KUBECONFIG is set

const runningPod = {kind: 'Pod', apiVersion, metadata } // Your Pod name/namspace 

 await cluster.
            begin('Copy authorization_keys')
            .exec(runningPod, ['mkdir', '-p', '/data/.ssh'])
            .exec(runningPod, ['cp', '/data/keys/authorized_keys', '/data/.ssh'])
            .end()
```

alternatively, you could use `kubectl exec` to execute commands in a Pod.

Finally, you could also use the CodeZero PostgreSQL provisioner (bash/NodeJS) to install and setup your ProstgreSQL https://github.com/c6o/provisioners

Comment: The problem is that this will run everytime the container launches. I only need to run the script when deploying a new Docker image (a new version of the micro-service)

Comment: You can run `kubeclt exec` or the `kubeclient` code from outside by setting the `KUBECONFIG` env variable. This will access the Pod inside the cluster. Most CI/CD's allow you to have secrets/environment variables.